# Why there is no right padding in td for blackberry phone

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to apply `padding:3px` to a `td` but it is not applying to the right side of the `td` when you re-size the window

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV8bh/2/) I tried

**Check this in chrome and have a look at my screenshot.**

**Screenshot** ( *look at the right side of the image, there is no padding applied*)

[image]

---

When I use inline-block to image it works in browser but not in blackberry phone

Comment: padding is applied there , change its to large value and try

Comment: Padding is there. i just resized it and checked by firebug and its there.

Comment: padding is there but it is not applied to the right side. It works if I remove the image border

Comment: padding is applying there. please chenge to large value and try

Comment: What browser are you experiencing this in?

Comment: chrome. it works when u increase the value but then also it is not equal all the sides

Comment: I can confirm the described behavior using Chromium 18. The padding has not the same amount on all sides (missing some on the right), i.e. the image is not centered properly. This is even true, when setting the padding to higher values, e.g. `1em`. The right padding becomes visible, when removing the `min-width: 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is a problem in combining `max-width` and `border` on an `image` element. The border is not counted to the width in [the default CSS box model](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/boxmodel). Thus the image get moved horizontally to the right be the width of the left border.

There are some possible workarounds, that came to my mind:

**A)** Use **`box-sizing: border-box;`** on the image element to switch to the formerly historical box model that is used by Internet Explorer in Quirks mode.

See [CSS poperty `box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing).

An example for all browsers, using [box-sizing-polyfill](https://github.com/Schepp/box-sizing-polyfill) here to achieve this box model for IE6 & IE7 without switching to Quirks mode:

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
*behavior: url(js/boxsizing.htc);
```

**B)** Set the **`max-width` of the image to `98%`**. When using This method, you also must find decrease the bottom padding of the surrounding element, in your case the table cell.

**C)** Move the **image** to the left by the width of it's left border: **`margin: 0 0 0 -2px;`**.
This would center the image, but the horizontal paddings are smaller by the width of the left and right borders.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display: block` instead of your `max-width: 100%` for your image in css. Hope that will work for you.

Comment: I cant remove max-width coz image needs to be re-sized when seen in different devices