# Image appearance in Blackberry mobile phone

Tags: html, css, mobile, blackberry, css-tables

There is a simple table which has an image on the left td. Image has 2px border.

This is working all fine in browsers but when I checked in Blackberry phone, image is not displaying because of `display:inline-block`.

Here I have given border to anchor tag around the image. If I give border directly to image then the td padding problem occurs as I mentioned in my [**previous question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860425/why-there-is-no-right-padding-in-td-for-blackberry-phone).

```
a.img{display:inline-block; border: 2px solid #800080; text-decoration:none}
```

So how can I get the proper code to work both in Blackberry and browser?

Here is the **[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/p7cBS/2/)** which is working perfect in browsers.

Comment: What version of BB is this: Seems that command is ok on latest:
http://caniuse.com/inline-block

Answer (score 0):

Have you given all display methods a try?  How about

```
display:block;
```

instead of

```
display:inline-block;?
```

According to Blackberry Browser 5.0, your code should still work.
Ref: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11846/Display_564489_11.jsp

Which Browser are you using?